# Latitude/Longitude Precision

Tags: geolocation

How precise are latitude and longitude combinations for the below cases:

- To the second decimal point (like Lat 41.11 and Long -90.12).
- To the third decimal point (like Lat 41.111 and Long -90.124).
- To the fourth decimal point (like Lat 41.1125 and Long -90.1278).

What I'm looking for is how precise does a latitude/longitude need to be to isolate a specific home address (ie: how many decimal places would it need to go to?).  It seems that this wouldn't apply to apartments (multiple floors would still be same lat/longs), possible condos, etc; but for homes it might offer precision to a point.

Comment: How good is your algebra and unit conversion? Figure you maybe want 200 foot resolution for medium suburban plot? There are 5280 feet in a mile. 360 degrees in a circle. The circumference of the earth is ~25,000 miles. Assuming you're lat/long is in degrees, that's, `(200*360)/(5280*25000)` or about `0.0005` resolution. Roughly... Adjust assumptions to taste.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: @lurker You're right, the right place for this question is https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a good answer to this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674

Answer (score 1):

At the equator a degree of latitude and longitude are both about 110Km. A degree of latitude stays roughly the same as you move away from the equator, but a degree of longitude scales with the cosine of the latitude -- so that at 60 N, a degree of longitude is about 55Km.

4 decimal places would be around 11m accuracy.